# Exclude few requests which are getting HTTP status code 400

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, loadrunner, beanshell

Hi I have a scenario in which i have 2 API's, I'm getting random number of dynamic vlaues from API 1 using a post processor. I need to process all these values in API2, for this requirement I'm using a V function to pass all the values in the URl by using a loop and counter. All the values are getting passed but some of the requests are getting HTTP status code 400, I need to exclude these requests which are getting 400 code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. Either amend your Post-Processor configuration to filter "unwanted" values
2. Or remove the values from JMeter Variables using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
3. Or investigate why the requests fail. One reason I can think of is that extracted responses contain characters which [cannot be used in the URL string](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/url-encoded-characters-reference/) and they need to be [url-encoded](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode).